# How to ask for columns when plotting graphs in R- Script

Tags: r

I am trying to make a script to allows user to decide what column will be chosen for the graph (slope, r - value, p - value, ect.). However I am having trouble. I know that when I read it in, the data type is a string. How do i convert it to a compatible type so I can use it as a column name? Here is an example of the script:

```
print("State the file name (include .csv)")

filename <- readline()

file <- read.csv(filename)

print("State the variable to be plotted")

var <- readline()

hist(file$var)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
y = data[, "colname"]
```

to extract 'colname' variable into a vector y (Don't forget the comma).

Or you can use

```
y = data[["colname"]]
```

Or even using `backtick quotes`

```
col.name = "colname"
y = data[`col.name`]
```

#### Your code:

```
filename = readline()
data = read.csv(filename)
colname = readline()

hist(data[, colname])
```